# SSRS 2012: Cannot access ReportExecution2005.asmx

Tags: sql-server, web-services, reporting-services

SSRS has two WebService endpoints that I care about: ReportService2010.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx.

I can access the ReportService2010 service just fine.

http://[report_server]/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx

But when I try to access ReportExecution2005.asmx, which is located in the same location on the report server. I get an error.

http://[report_server]/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and 
then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A string literal was expected, but no opening quote character was found.     
Error processing resource
```

EDIT: I am using a custom authentication dll, though I'm not sure that should matter when just trying to access the service wsdl.

UPDATE: It appears to be an access denied error. Though I'm not sure why access is denied to one service, but not the other.

**UPDATE FIXED:**
I updated the my web.config and added the following configuration:

`<location path="ReportExecution2005.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE FIXED:**
I updated the my web.config and added the following configuration:

`<location path="ReportExecution2005.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

Comment: I've run into the same thing now recently, where sometimes the ReportService2005 is not reachable (permission denied) and other times the ReportService2010 endpoint is not.  I haven't been able to figure out what is causing it, but it seems to happen when a load balancer is in use, though no idea how that could be contributing to it all.  Anyway, thanks for the tip on this, it's working for now.

Comment: I've experienced the same behavior, but there was no load balancer involved. (Those same 2 of the 4 .asmx files get access-denied Html pages, but the other 2 do not.) The indicated answer/fix works around the problem adequately.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification for anyone else who has this problem.
Part of the instructions for creating a custom security extension involves adding these lines to the SSRS web.config:

```
<authorization> 
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Like the README.MD says, "this will deny unauthenticated users the right to access the report server."  If your goal is to enable anonymous access, you will need to change this line.

One option is what the OP did above:

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Another is to remove the offending line completely:

```
<authorization>
authorization>
```